# React-Router ignoring nested routes on server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, react-router

I am trying to use Express.js to render a React application on the server side. However, it seems that some of my routes are being skipped over and I'm not sure why.

### My server.js

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        console.log(routes);

  match(
    { routes: routes, location: req.url },
    (err, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).send(err.message);
      }
      if (redirectLocation) {
        return res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search);
      }
      let markup;
      if (renderProps) {
        var InitialComponent = (
          <Provider store={store}>
              <RouterContext {...renderProps} />
          </Provider>
        );
        markup = renderToString(InitialComponent);
      } else {
        markup = renderToString(<NotFoundPage/>);
        res.status(404);
      }
      return res.render('index', { markup });
    }
  );
});
```

### Routes.js

```
export let routes = (

  <Route path="/" component={TransitionContainer}>
      <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
      <Route path="home" component={Home}/>
      <Route path="bom/:bomID/" component={BOM}/>
        <IndexRoute component={BomItemsGrid}/>
        <Route path="grid" component={BomItemsGrid}/>
        <Route path="table" component={BomItemsTable}/>
      <Route path="*" component={NotFoundPage}/>
    </Route>


)
```

When I navigate to `/bom/6/table` I get a React tree of the following

```
Provider
  Router
    RouterContext
      TransitionContainer
        NotFoundPage
```

It skips the `BOM` component defined in the `/bom/:bomID/` route for some reason and just renders `NotFoundPage`.

Why can't `match()` find the route even though it's defined?

Comment: Does changing the route from `path="bom/:bomID/"` to `path="bom/:bomID"` work? I'm wondering if the extra slash is throwing off routing.

Comment: just tried it, no change @KeithA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh I missed it. You're not closing the BOM route. This:

```
<Route path="bom/:bomID/" component={BOM}/>
```

should be:

```
<Route path="bom/:bomID/" component={BOM}> //<--- notice: No slash
  <IndexRoute component={BomItemsGrid}/>
  <Route path="grid" component={BomItemsGrid}/>
  <Route path="table" component={BomItemsTable}/>
</Route> //<--- add this
```

Comment: Don't be. It happens to us all. I had a similar mistake like this a few times. At least it was a simple minor mistake. It could have been harder to find.

Comment: yep. Any idea why I'd be getting errors like `Uncaught Error: Unable to find element with ID 13.` now on the client side? It works fine if I load a different page and then navigate to the route, but gives me this error if I load that route directly. @KeithA

Comment: Based on the code above I don't. Is the debugger throwing the file and line number at all?

Comment: It is stemming from `ReactDOMComponent.receiveComponent (ReactDOMComponent.js:710)` but there aren't any of my files in the stack trace.. @KeithA Maybe we should take this to PM? is that even possible with SO?